# LINQ C# question

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following structure:

```
class A
{
public Int32 ID {get; set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

List alreadyCreated, List newlyCreated and I want to obtain the Ids of the newly created, if their date is diferrent from the date with the most occurences in the alreadyCreated. The alreadyCreated contains the newlyCreated.
I have the following LINQ:

```
var result = (from ClassA newCreated in newlyCreated
              group newCreated by newCreated .Date
              into groups
              // select the "correct" date
              let correctDate = (from ge in group
                                 from ce in newlyCreated               
                                 where groupEvents.Count() == groupEvents.Max(gr =>groupEvents.Count())
                                       && ge.ID != ce.ID
                                  select ge).FirstOrDefault() 
             //select the "incorrect" ones
             let incorrectDates= (from ge in group
                                 join ce in newlyCreated on ge.ID equals ce.ID
                                 where DateTime.Compare(ge.EventDateGMT,eventWithCorrectDate.EventDateGMT) !=0
                                 select ge).ToList()  
             select new { CorrectDate= correctDate, IncorrectDates= incorrectDates}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Everything works fine , except the DateTime.Compare, basically if I have newly created with a different Date then the oldycreated, the incorrectDates list is empty.I have also tried with DateTime.Equals and with date1 != date2 .Same result. Without the `where DateTime.Compare(ge.EventDateGMT,eventWithCorrectDate.EventDateGMT) !=0`, all newly created records are returned (the list of alreadyCreated contains the list of newlyCreated).
Where is the problem?

Comment: not the ge.EventDateGMT.Subtract(eventWithCorrectDate.EventDateGMT)
.CompareTo(new TimeSpan(0)) !=0 worked , I will have to change the linq in another way

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought:

```
ge.EventDateGMT.Subtract(eventWithCorrectDate.EventDateGMT)
.CompareTo(new TimeSpan(0)) !=0
```

Hope this helps